# Include a link to the question checklist on the How to Ask page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

In the off topic close screen it includes a link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist which is a very good post, however the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page does not contain a link to the checklist.

It would be nice if a link to the question checklist was added to the how to ask page, I think the theme of the Question Checklist and the How To Ask page go well together and would not fit well under any of the other categories under the "Asking" subsection.